# Remove UICollectionViewCell via custom button

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

This approach removes random cell, but not the one I want. I think problem is in initializing the button with indexPath and I don't know how to fix it.

If I'm not mistaken, indexPath.item indicates a row in UICollectionView. So where is the bug?

```
extension UIButton {

    struct Holder {
        static var _myComputedProperty:IndexPath!
    }
    var indexPath:IndexPath {
        get {
            return Holder._myComputedProperty
        }
        set(newValue) {
            Holder._myComputedProperty = newValue
        }
    }
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrRequest.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! RequestCell
    cell.delete.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.delete.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(del(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 235)
}

@objc func del(sender: UIButton) {

    arrRequest.remove(at: sender.indexPath.item)

    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sender.indexPath])
    }) { (finished) in
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can set a button tag with the row of indexPath. Then handle it in del function.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints and/or logging what things are? Usually you can see this stuff if you just print or use p/po commands in the debugger (LLDB)

Comment: @StephenJ I printed indexPath in collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) and it seems it works correctly. Then I passed the cell obj to the action function and added `guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }` and guard statement always false. Also I wanted to refactor my code with custom delegate to cell, but wtf [f() ins't called](https://pastebin.com/Yc3gZP27) . Please, explain how to properly use UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: Collections and Table views just need a full understanding of the animation system, run loops, and threading... I'm unsure what your bug is unless data from one source is erased before expected, cross-referenced, or something is on a callback that moves it to a new thread... it's probably simpler though. I'm fairly certain this has to do with the index + timing of change

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code like below

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! RequestCell
    cell.delete.tag = index path.row
    cell.delete.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(del(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

And your delete method will be as follows:

```
@objc func del(sender: UIButton) {

let indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0)

    arrRequest.remove(at: indexPath)

    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    }) { (finished) in
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    } 
}
```

Comment: `arrRequest.remove(at: indexPath)` compilation error, `arrRequest.remove(at: indexPath.item)` runtime error

Comment: replace .row with .item since it's UICollectionV. He got mixed with tables